# Make proc available to all modulefiles?

Tags: linux, module, tcl, modulefile

I'm using [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) to manage software. I'm trying to set up the environment so that a certain function can be called from any modulefile without each file having to source the proc definition.

Example: I want the `util:prereq` function to be available in the following modulefile without having to source its definition:

```
#%Module1.0

util::prereq compiler_intel/13.0.1 mpi/openmpi-1.6.4_intel-13.0.1
```

In order to do this I know I'll have to hook into modulefiles or tcl or something. Any ideas?

The usage of this function is similar to `prereq` except that the function will load any  prerequisites instead of failing because it isn't loaded.

Comment: I wonder what the contents of the global `auto_path` variable is at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way than clarkw suggested is to use the old `tclIndex` file.

This file has to be in the folders `$auto_path` or a subdirectory of them (subdirectory suggested).
You can create the `tclIndex` file either by hand or by invoking

```
auto_mkindex directory file.tcl
```

Again: directory should be a (sub-)directory of `$auto_path`
This will source your tcl file if one of it's command is used for the first time.